# How to get verbatimTextOutput inline with regular text in Shiny app?

Tags: r, shiny

When running this simple app, I come across a problem where the **-** between the `verbatimTextOutput` for scores is not aligned properly with the output text boxes (or potentially vice versa).  I know that `verbatimTextOutput` includes the text in an HTML pre tag and when I inspect element I can see that it is allocating some sort of bottom margin to the text box output.  When I remove the margin for this pre tag using inspect element the text boxes line up perfectly with the **-**.  How can I make this happen as the default?

[Essentially how can I go from this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LfHW.png)

[To this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OLll2.png)

```
library(shiny)

A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

uiMatchup <- fluidPage(
  fluidRow(
    column(3,
           selectInput(
             inputId = "Away",
             label = h3("Away Team"),
             choices = c(A, B)),
           align="center"),
    column(3,
           selectInput(
             inputId = "Home",
             label = h3("Home Team"),
             choices = c(A,B)
           ),
           align="center",
           offset=6)
  ),
  
  br(),
  
  fluidRow(
    column(5,
           verbatimTextOutput("Team1Score"),
           align="center"),
    column(2, 
           h3("-"),
           align="center"),
    column(5,
           verbatimTextOutput("Team2Score"),
           align="center")
  )
)

serverMatchup <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$Team1Score <- renderPrint({

      return(cat(paste0(input$Away)))
    })

  output$Team2Score <- renderPrint({

    return(cat(paste0(input$Home)))
    }) 
  
}

shinyApp(ui = uiMatchup, server = serverMatchup)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally answered my own question.  I simply created a renderText output that is just a dash and then created a tag for the Dash textOutput where I manually set the position of the dash to be horizontally and vertically aligned with the other inputs.

```
library(shiny)

A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)
B <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7)

uiMatchup <- fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
        column(3,
               selectInput(
                   inputId = "Away",
                   label = h3("Away Team"),
                   choices = c(A, B)),
               align="center"),
        column(3,
               selectInput(
                   inputId = "Home",
                   label = h3("Home Team"),
                   choices = c(A,B)
               ),
               align="center",
               offset=6)
    ),
    
    br(),
    
    fluidRow(
        column(5,
               verbatimTextOutput("Team1Score"),
               align="center"),
        column(2, 
               textOutput("Dash"),
               align="center"),
        column(5,
               verbatimTextOutput("Team2Score"),
               align="center")
    ),
    tags$style(type='text/css', "#Dash { width:100%; margin-top:-10px; font-size: 40px;
                                 font-style: bold;}")
)

serverMatchup <- function(input, output) {
    
    output$Team1Score <- renderPrint({
        
        return(cat(paste0(input$Away)))
    })
    
    output$Team2Score <- renderPrint({
        
        return(cat(paste0(input$Home)))
    })
    
    output$Dash <- renderText({"-"
    })
    
}

shinyApp(ui = uiMatchup, server = serverMatchup)
```